# Hidden keylogger, is it possible?

Tags: email, powershell, passwords, virus, phishing

Hello Stack comminity!

I need your advices and professional help...

Is it possible to have hidden keylogger via MS PowerShell?

Here is my story, several days ago I opened attachment of my trusted friend...
It was some .vbs script. Yes I've been caught... I got original Win10, so virus has been found and removed, actually there was several other messages by Win10 firewall, so I downloaded ESET NOD, one virus found and removed.

Second part of the story is an blackmailing email with one of my passwords in the title - phishing:

[like this](https://www.businessinsider.es/new-email-scam-uses-old-password-fake-porn-threats-webcam-video-bitcoin-2018-7?r=US&IR=T)

Fortunately I didin't use both this e-mail and password in some important places...

I immiedately change all of my passwords, I added double protection...

**Question is, are my new passwords safe now?**

What about this PowerShell.exe in System32, should I be worried? The blue window just sometimes pop up... Usually when I plug my laptop to the energy source...

**Is it possible to have some hidden keylogger (both ESET NOD and Win10 don't detect it) or other trash that monitor my activity and passwords?**

I'll be grateful for any advices!

Comment: Aside of your question, those emails with your password in the title are scammers. They don't actually have your password. You can delete the email and forget about it and nothing will happen. I've received them myself and many of my clients too over the span of 2 to 3 months now and nothing seriously has happened since. That said, opening a .vbs file can do many things and it is impossible for us to tell if you are safe now. To be sure, reinstall windows.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have the original verision of Win10 and it's associated with my MS account. Do you think, the Recovery, Reset this PC option in settings with removal of all files will be enough?

Comment: Yes, that will be enough.